# Post data to multiple tables MVC EF6

Tags: jquery, database, model-view-controller, one-to-many

Within my MVC application I have a form that I want to post data to multiple tables.  I was wondering how I can achieve this?
Here is the code for my controller and also the code for my view.

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id_index,createddate,details,options")] tbl_info tbl_info)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.tbl_info.Add(tbl_info);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(tbl_info);
    }
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>The Form</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.createddate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.createddate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.createddate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.details, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.details, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.details, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.options, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.options, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.options, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

The user can add many options (the options input can be cloned via jquery) and I need those options to be posted to a seperate table which has a one to many relationship with tbl_info.  Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Your models will need to be setup something like so:

```
public class tbl_info
{
  public int tbl_infoID {get; set;}
  public string details {get; set;}
  etc ...

  public virtual ICollection<tbl_options> Options {get; set;}
}

public class tbl_options
{
  public int id {get; set;}
  public int tbl_infoID {get; set;}
  public string option_value {get; set;}
}
```

Then in your view you have to name each option like Model.Options[0].option_value. You have to increment the [0]; [0], [1] etc. You must not skip any numbers and it needs to start at 0 so MVC can associate your form objects to your Options model.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.options, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Options[0].option_value, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Options[0].option_value, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.options, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Options[1].option_value, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Options[1].option_value, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

****Edit

Your controller should look something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(tbl_info myModel)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    db.tbl_info.Add(myModel);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  return View(myModel);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  How would the controller handle this?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  If I add this to my code I get an error in my view of: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection 
I tried changing ICollection to IList, this fixes the error however when I submit my form no data is actually posted to the database at all.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  If I add this to my code I get an error in my view of: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection 
I tried changing ICollection to IList, this fixes the error however when I submit my it only posts the data to one table, the other data is just lost.